# How do I replace credential parameters in a power-shell script with a PSCredential object?

Tags: c#, powershell, automation

I am using C# to add the following script to a PowerShell instance.  I want to automate this so how can I replace the -Credential parameter with a PSCredential object that I created? Also, can I use a different PSCredential object for my LocalCredential?  I know how to create a PSCredential object.  I just don't know how to insert it into my ps.AddScript method.

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName '"+ strMachineName + @"' -LocalCredential '.\Administrator' -DomainName 'MyDomain' -Credential MyDomain\MyUserName -Restart -Force");
```

My exact code:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ComputerName = strMachineName;

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()
ps.AddScript(@"Add-Computer -ComputerName '"+ strMachineName + @"' -LocalCredential '.\Administrator' -DomainName 'MyDomain' -Credential MyDomain\Username -Restart -Force");

ps.Runspace = runspace;

ps.Invoke();
```

I changed my code per Mathias R. Jessen's suggestion.  My goal is to add a new machine on the same Lan to the domain.  I try to capture the ObjectModelCollection collection from the Invoke method to see if I can learn anything by the collection returned. 
 The collection count is 0 after the invoke method is called and the remote machine does not restart.  Please see my revised code.

REVISED CODE

```
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            //secureString for a Domain user on the domain that I want to 
             join the remote PC to
            System.Security.SecureString secureString1 = new 
            NetworkCredential("DomainAdminUserName", DomainPassword").SecurePassword; 

            //secureString for a loca Administrator on the remote machine
            System.Security.SecureString secureString2 = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "AdminPassword").SecurePassword;

            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            PSCredential localCred = new PSCredential("Administrator", secureString2);
            PSCredential domainCred = new PSCredential("DomainAdminUserName", secureString1); //UNDONE Should not be Greer
            ps.AddCommand("Add-Computer")
              .AddParameter("ComputerName", strMachineName)
              .AddParameter("LocalCredential", localCred)
              .AddParameter("DomainName", "MyDomain")
              .AddParameter("Credential", domainCred)
              .AddParameter("Restart")
              .AddParameter("Force");

            try
            {
                //INVOKE
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject> coll = ps.Invoke();
                blnSuccess = true;                    
            }
            catch
            {
                blnSuccess = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                runspace.Close();
            }
            return blnSuccess;
```

UPDATE

Everything is working now.  I was being blocked by the firewall on the remote PC.  The only way I know to disable the firewall on the remote machine is to use PSEXEC from Sysinternals as follows:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PsExec.exe"; 

        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;     

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\<REMOTEPCNAME> -u Administrator -p <PASSWORD> netsh firewall set opmode disable";


        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

If there is a way to accomplish this in Powershell without using PSEXEC I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AddCommand()` followed by `AddParameter()` instead of `AddScript()`:

```
PSCredential localCred = ...;
PSCredential domainCred = ...;

ps.AddCommand("Add-Computer")
  .AddParameter("ComputerName", strMachineName)
  .AddParameter("LocalCredential", localCred)
  .AddParameter("DomainName", "MyDomain")
  .AddParameter("Credential", domainCred)
  .AddParameter("Restart")
  .AddParameter("Force");
```

Comment: I changed my code to reflect your suggestion.  I'm not getting any errors but the remote machine is not joining the domain nor restarting.  I tried grabbing the results of the Invoke method to learn more but the collection count is 0.  Any further suggestion

Comment: Maybe it's the firewall on the remote machine.  I'll try disabling it via calling PSEXEC from code.  Not sure it will work against an instance of Server 2012 but I'll give it a try (psexec \\ComputerHostname netsh firewall set opmode disable).

Comment: I called PSEXEC from my C# program and used it to disable the firewall on the remote PC.  Updated my post to let all know what worked.

Comment: @BillGreer Cool, glad you figured it out!

Comment: now all I have to do is figure out how to disable the Domain networks firewall for another method in the same project. My code only disables the firewall for the Private networks.  :)

Comment: @BillGreer I'd strongly advice against it. Once you've joined the machines do AD you can easily manage the firewall rules via GPO

Comment: I was under the impression the Domain firewall had to be off so I could join the domain using PowerShell remotely.  I'll have to test.

Comment: @BillGreer Domain profile won't be active until _after_ they've been joined to the domain

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the AddCommand() and AddParameter() methods instead of AddScript().

Then, you can create a PSCredential object in code and pass it to AddParameter().